# A good way to write a 1 byte char array into a binary file created by C++

Tags: java

I need to parse a binary file created by **C++** and overwrite a 4 char long **char array** in that file, for example change the original char array of ABCD to WXYZ.

I know exactly the position in terms of bytes of the that char array. I tried **RandomAccessFile** which let me go to the position easily. But I cannot make the rest work for me right now.

Is the RandomAccessFile a right way to go?

I know I have to do some conversion from **2 bytes char** to **one byte char**.

Anybody has a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine: always try the JavaDoc [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

```
long position = ...;
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { (byte)'W', ... };
raf.seek(position);
raf.write(bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

`RandomAccessFile` is fine. As you have already figured out, in C++ `char` is a single byte, whereas Java uses [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

The easiest option might be to use `byte[4]` in your code to represent the 4-character ASCII string.